# How to get the width of a Node?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

The idea is that I have a parent Node as a container with a bunch of Sprites as children, and that I can have the Node's width include the width of the children, since I'm assuming the size would encompass its children, but it doesn't look like it.

I've got a subclass of `Node`, with several sprites added to it via `addChild`, but the content size returned by `subclassofNode()->getContentSize().width` is always `0`.

Is it possible to get an accurate size of a Node?

Comment: Did you get anything done in that regard? I would love to see how you have solved this. There are plenty of things that would affect width and height of the container node, including scaling of child nodes and their rotation [not to mention their position]

Comment: @Krystian I think you'd need to handle all that manually. Like you said, go through all the children and account for scaling, and even positioning.  I ended up moving to a different subclass to solve my problem, like Sprites, then eventually `ui::Widget`s. Definitely recommend a `ui::Widget` for any positioning stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node has a size always equals to zero.
you should subclass of CCSprite instead.

If you want to do it in this way, you would need to override the fuction "GetContentSize"

Comment: Interesting. I'm using 3.4, so I believe `CCSprite` is just `Sprite` now. So `getContentSize` isn't supposed to account for its children?

Comment: If you have serval sprite in the sprite(/node), you need to override the function. 
sprite would only account the own one(when init call).

Comment: Alright, so I can't get the size of child sprites, since the parent's content size doesn't adjust passed the first child sprite.  I must be doing something weird, now that my subclass is from Sprite instead of Node, I'm getting an access violation in `main.cpp`, having changed nothing else. Only in the windows build, not the android one. As soon as the parent node gets drawn or something.

Comment: Using node is ok and you also need to override the getContentSize

Comment: I'll look into it some more and get back to you. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I rebuilt cocos2d in debug, so I was able to see what happened: Since I was creating a node in a nonstandard way, when I changed it to Sprite, it was trying to draw a texture that didn't exist, so `Texture2D::getName` segfaulted because the texture was `NULL`.  Thanks again for your help. I'll need to find a better way to see how big a node is.